# Android - recognizer results null... need to put them into cursor ()

Tags: java, android

I need the results from recognizer in my cursor statement below:

```
 if (requestCode == check && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        ArrayList<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,      ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + "=?", new String[]{ results }, null);
```

problem is the 'results' in line below:

```
 ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + "=?", new String[]{ results }, null);
```

Does not accept my 'results' string as it is an arraylist variable and not string... the reults are from recognizer and when I say a word it converts to text, but i need either a real string set to get the cursor code to take or ?? thanks

Comment: Wat exactly is the question? Is getting null from recognizer or not able to form the query string? Can you be more clear?

Comment: I redid the code eaxmples and some text in question to help make more clear. thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are what you can do:

1) If your result is just one contact and `results` contains only one item.

```
 Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, 
    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + "=?",
      new String[]{ results.get(0) }, null);
```

2) Now looking at your logic, you are trying to get all contacts with what user spoke. So if the results contain more than one item, it looks like then results is containing first name, last name etc. You should build the selection arg string as

```
StringBuilder selectionArgStr = new StringBuilder();
for(String word : results) { 
   selectionArgStr.append(word);
   selectionArgStr.append(" ");
}

Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, 
   ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + "=?",
     new String[]{ selectionArgStr.toString() }, null);
```

3) If the results contain different names of different people, then we need to build selection string instead as :

```
StringBuilder selectionStr = new StringBuilder();
int resultLen = results.size();
for(int i=0; i<resultLen; i++) { 
   selectionStr.append(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
   selectionStr.append("=?");
   if(i>0 && i<(resultLen -1)) // Put OR only if there are more than one
     selectionStr.append(" || ");
}


Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, 
   selectionStr,
     (String [])results.toArray(), null);
```

Comment: how can i make it ignore case (upper/lower) from results?

Comment: i think results should be coming all lower case ? are they not?

Comment: yes they are, sorry. Perhaps the results need to be compared to phone table and then call closest match w/o asking if its correct. So if we have result Susan and we have one susan in our contacts it will call it otherwise display options of which one need be selected...even if their is a last or first name.. i suppose it would have to search both fields.. new question? .. you are VERY helpful. =)

Comment: i think `DISPLAY_NAME` should contain both first name and last name. So you can try sql `like` keyword instead of `=`

Comment: LIKE THIS:?: Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + "=", new String[]{ results.get(0) }, null); << OR >> Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + "like", new String[]{ results.get(0) }, null); ?? Thank you.

Comment: `ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " like %?%"`. % means it will match anything on the left side and right side. BTW you dont need to do args if you are not reusing the query. This will work too `ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " like %" + results.get(0) + "%"` and then pass `null` for `new String[]{ results.get(0) }`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6530/discussion-between-havexz-and-david)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
startmanagingCursor(cur);
cur.moveToFirst();
```